# Collection with natural order and update of elements under certain conditions

Tags: java, collections, java-7

my use case is the following:

I have certain element that I would like to insert using natural order (in my case let's say is a list of prices starting from the cheaper).

The objects I have to store follows this class:

```
class Article { int id; int price; }
```

- I want to update the item in the Collection only if the price follows
  certain conditions.
- I would like also to keep elements ordered
  according to price.

I was thinking of a `TreeSet` but the `Set` doesn't have a `get` method so updating an element, in my experience, would require to iterate the Set to find the right object.

Right now I opted for a `List` that I order when needed, but I'm quite curious if you think there is Collection that can fullfill my requirements or if there is a better approach.

Thanks

Comment: A `TreeMap<Integer, Article>`? Although price would have to be unique. You can also search a `TreeSet` by using a "template object" - use it to find the next element higher or lower than the template.

Comment: Do you mean ceiling for example?

Comment: Yes, depending on how much searching you need to do, this should be sufficient. You can use the Flyweight Pattern so that you don't need to keep creating objects and `ceiling()` is `O(lg n)` which is probably sufficient.

Comment: Everytime an article is added, I have to check if exists, and in that case just update the price article under certain conditions.

Comment: What are the search criteria? Of the ordering is on `price` then you will always have to do a `O(n)` search to find an article by some different criteria.

Comment: Exactly. The search would be of course based on the id of the article but the order must be done according to price. I still think using a List and then order it is ok.

Comment: It depends. Inserting into a `TreeSet` would be `O(lg n)` and searching would be `O(n)`. Inserting into a `List` would require you to sort it, this would be `O(n lg n)` - much more expensive. And searching would still be `O(n)`. I don't think a `List` is a good fit. Just make sure your comparator is **consistent wirh `equals`**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59862/discussion-between-dierre-and-boris-the-spider).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, basically you just want your elements to follow an order :
You can use combination of `Collections.sort()` and a class which implementing `Comparator<E>`.

```
  import java.util.*;

 // class used to compare "price"
class priceComparator implements Comparator<Article> {

@Override
public int compare(Article o1, Article o2) {
    return o1.price - o2.price;    
  } 
 }

  public class Article {

  int id;
  int price;

  public Article(int id, int price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.price = price;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Article> list = new ArrayList<>();
     list.add(new Article(1, 4000));
     list.add(new Article(2, 7000)); 
     list.add(new Article(3, 1000)); 

        // sorting Article based on "price" ASCENDING
        Collections.sort(list, new priceComparator());

        // sorting Article based on "price" DESCENDING
       //Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder(new priceComparator()));

       // put the sorted pair of "id" and "price" into map
       Map<Integer,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

      for(Article l : list){
      map.put(l.id, l.price);  
      }


    System.out.println("Id | Price");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> elemenOfMap: map.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(elemenOfMap.getKey() +" | "+elemenOfMap.getValue());
    }       
   }
}
```

The output :

```
Id | Price
3 | 1000
1 | 4000
2 | 7000
```